jQuery click triggers click event handler 3 times
I tried to implement a simple website which have 5 checkboxes.
If user clicks "All" checkbox then all the other checkbox will be checked or unchecked depends on the value of the "All" checkbox.


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#all").click(function(event) {
    console.log("all");
    $("input[name=vehicle]").each(function() {
      $(this).click();
    });
  });
});

function checkVehicle(event, id) {
  // console.log(event);
  console.log(id);
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <input type="checkbox" id="all" name="all" />
  <label for="all">All</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="car" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event, 1)" />
  <label>Car</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="bike" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event, 2)" />
  <label>Bike</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="truck" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event, 3)" />
  <label>Truck</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="tank" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event,4)" />
  <label>Tank</label>



The problem is when I click "All" checkbox the checkVehicle for each other checkbox is called 3 times.
I am interested in knowing the reason behind this behaviour rather than how to fix it.
I could solve the problem by using one of the below methods.
First one is instead of triggering click event on jQuery element I could trigger it on DOM element.
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#all").click(function(event) {
    console.log("all");
    $("input[name=vehicle]").each(function() {
      $(this)[0].click();
    });
  });
});

function checkVehicle(event, id) {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(id);
}

Second one is instead of registering event inline I could register it programmatically.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>

  <input type="checkbox" id="all" name="all" />
  <label for="all">All</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="car" name="vehicle" />
  <label>Car</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="bike" name="vehicle" />
  <label>Bike</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="truck" name="vehicle" />
  <label>Truck</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="tank" name="vehicle" />
  <label>Tank</label>

</html>

And here is my index.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#all").click(function(event) {
    console.log("all");
    $("input[name=vehicle]").each(function() {
      $(this).click();
    });
  });

  $("input[name=vehicle]").click(function() {
    console.log("personal");
  });

});


Why all labels has same for="all" instead of actual input ID?

@Justinas
Thanks for your comment. I remove the unnecessary for attributes in the labels.

"I am interested in knowing the reason behind this behaviour" - you have onclick="checkVehicle(event, ...) on each of your checkboxes expect the "all" one, plus you add an additional click hander to each of them in your JS - and when "all" is clicked, you explicitly trigger a pseudo-click on all of them, with $(this).click(); in the loop - which then of course triggers event handlers you added to them.

If you don't want this to trigger the click handlers on the checkboxes, then you should not be clicking them via JS to begin with, but manipulate the value of their checked property instead. And instead of click handler, change handlers are rather preferable for checkboxes.

@Karan
Sorry if my description is not clear enough.
The problem is the click handler for each checkbox is invoked exactly 3 times.
The console log output would be (1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4).
If I change the code as one of two methods I suggested then each click handler will be invoked once and the output would be as following (1 2 3 4).

@nammae88, I got your point. It seems that it has to do with jQuery version. I tried with older version with jQuery3.3.1 & older its working as expected. With jQuery4.0.0 or newer versions it triggers click event 3 times.

it is happening because you applied a loop over all $("input[name=vehicle]") and in side loop you are triggering click event

you don't need to trigger click for all other check-boxes, instead make property checked either true or false

@C3roe, it seems that we misunderstood the question here. You can try with running code snippet and as per our expectation it should trigger click event for all inputs once. But what happens here is code $(this).click(); invokes respective onclick functions three times and you will notice output as The console log output would be (1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4) instead of (1 2 3 4).

Seems a bug in jQuery; introduced with version 3.4.0

Appears to be a bug in combination with those inline event handlers, more specifically. If I remove the onclick attributes, and instead add a click handler to those checkboxes using $("input[name=vehicle]").on('click', function(){  console.log(this.id) }); - then clicking the "all" checkbox logs the ID of each checkbox to the console only once.

You have bumped into a bug that was reported in 2019, issue #4493:

When calling $(...).click() on a checkbox input that has an onclick property defined, its callback gets called three times.
Apparently this behavior was introduced on 3.4.0.

The reply from a jQuery team member was:

Inline event handlers are notoriously unreliable, and we don't have much if any test coverage for them as a result. They are on our wontfix list for that reason.

And the wontfix list has:

Inline Event Handlers
In general, inline event handlers are incredibly hard to work with and should not be used. In nearly all cases, issues involving inline event handlers are out of scope. Inline handlers do not behave the same way as event handlers added with the standard DOM addEventListener method.

So there you have it. It is a known bug, and it wont be fixed.

When you call $(this).trigger('click'); inside the $("#all").click(function(event) { ... }); handler, it simulates a click event on each checkbox.
You could try by set prop value checked and then fire the function checkVehicle


$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#all").click(function (event) {
      console.log("all");
      $("input[name=vehicle]").each(function (e) {
          $(this).prop('checked', true);
          checkVehicle(e, $(this).attr('id'));
      });
   });
});

function checkVehicle(event, id) {
   console.log(id);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="all" name="all" />
<label for="all">All</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="car" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event, 1)" />
<label>Car</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="bike" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event, 2)" />
<label>Bike</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="truck" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event, 3)" />
<label>Truck</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="tank" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event,4)" />
<label>Tank</label>




As the comments clarified, if you only want the properties to be checked, then you should be able to do $("input[name=vehicle]").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked")) without the loop, jQuery will handle that for you:


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#all").click(function(event) {
    console.log("all");
    $("input[name=vehicle]").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"))/*.each(function() {
      $(this).click();
    });*/
  });
});

function checkVehicle(event, id) {
  // console.log(event);
  console.log(id);
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <input type="checkbox" id="all" name="all" />
  <label for="all">All</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="car" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event, 1)" />
  <label>Car</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="bike" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event, 2)" />
  <label>Bike</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="truck" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event, 3)" />
  <label>Truck</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="tank" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event,4)" />
  <label>Tank</label>



But, if you only wonder what happens under the hood, then take a look at this snippet:


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#all").click(function(event) {
    console.log("all");
    $("input[name=vehicle]").each(function() {
      this.click();
    });
  });
});

function checkVehicle(event, id) {
  // console.log(event);
  console.log(id);
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <input type="checkbox" id="all" name="all" />
  <label for="all">All</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="car" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event, 1)" />
  <label>Car</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="bike" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event, 2)" />
  <label>Bike</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="truck" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event, 3)" />
  <label>Truck</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="tank" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event,4)" />
  <label>Tank</label>



You will notice that without the jQuery object of $(this), the simple .click() of this will do what you want. So it's clearly related what "this" means inside your .each() callback. Note that this second script will negate your checkboxes, so if you manually checked a checkbox first and then click on all to check all, then the one you checked will be unchecked, which is unlikely to be your intention. You can enhance it like this:


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#all").click(function(event) {
    console.log("all");
    $("input[name=vehicle]").each(function() {
      if (this.checked !== event.target.checked) $(this).click();
    });
  });
});

function checkVehicle(event, id) {
  // console.log(event);
  console.log(id);
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <input type="checkbox" id="all" name="all" />
  <label for="all">All</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="car" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event, 1)" />
  <label>Car</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="bike" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event, 2)" />
  <label>Bike</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="truck" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event, 3)" />
  <label>Truck</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="tank" name="vehicle" onclick="checkVehicle(event,4)" />
  <label>Tank</label>



